# Error: spawn convert ENOENT while using request npm package

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, npm, buffer

My aim to obtain the `buffer` of the image which is `stored` in the s3 `bucket`. I am using a npm package named [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) which does a simple `http/https` request to the url provided on the s3 bucket. When I am using the package and doing the https request on the image url provided to me by s3 bucket I am getting the following error

```
 events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: spawn convert ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
at child_process.js:1144:20
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js) question on stackOverflow but couldn't find the resolution for my problem. My Code is as follows:

```
request(url, function (err, response,res1) {
                if (err) {
                    //error Handling;
                } else {
                    buffer = res1;
                    //Some Logic
                }
            });
```

Can Somebody help me with issue?

Comment: You're getting a binary response - you need to handle the .on('data') event.

Comment: Thanks Remus!!! I got to know that request has an options parameter where I had to set the encoding to null to get the buffer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading a binary file in javascript using browserify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541845/reading-a-binary-file-in-javascript-using-browserify)